# error spark-submit scala, ClassNotFoundException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, emr

I'm trying to run a scala application and in spark-shell this works well. But when I use spark-submit, using my class, it fails.

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi s3n://bucket/test.scala
```

Applicacion:

```
package org.apache.spark.examples

import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

object SparkPi {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

    print("test")

  }
}
```

Error:

> Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 10, (reason: Uncaught exception:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi)

Answer (score 1):

Try to build jar using your test.scala source and provide it as an argument for spark-submit. In spark-submit you should specify a jar with your compiled code, not the source code itself.

Comment: I compiled with SBT, no?

Comment: Yep, and got some `.class` files. Now pack them into a jar and use it to launch your job. According to a command that you provided you're specifying a source code `.scala` instead of compiled code.